# HashMap : Why i am able to get the 'value' for a 'key' which is of a type City class which do not override equals() or hashcode() methods?

Tags: hashmap, overriding

As per Kathy Sierra SCJP 6.0 book ( Chaper 7: Generics and Collections, Pg.583, Using Maps), i need to override the equals() and hashcode() methods of the class who's object i want to use as key, else i wont be able to find the value for that key.

But as per my code, i am able to get the value. Why?

```
import java.util.*;

class City {
    String name;

    City(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
        City c1 = new City("NewYork");
        map.put(c1, "Fashion Capital");
        System.out.println(map.get(c1));
    }

}
```

//Output is : "Fashion Capital"

Comment: Where have you overridden the equals() and hashcode() methods?

Comment: That is the query. Even if i have not overridden the methods i am able to find the element. Why ?